# How many plants are needed to survive in an airtight chamber?

Tags: botany, photosynthesis

How large a garden do you need if you are to survive on them producing enough oxygen in a closed chamber?

And which are the most effective plants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this news article](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1310&dat=19950809&id=5kZWAAAAIBAJ&sjid=GOsDAAAAIBAJ&pg=5465,1880502), in a NASA experiment one man survived for 15 days in a sealed chamber containing 30,000 small wheat plants. If you read the article you will find that this did not produce a completely balanced system - some excess oxygen had to be removed, and some extra CO<sub>2</sub> had to be pumped in.